# how to output a variable that is updated dynamically inside a step in jenkins console. config file ( environment file ) that I passed for a job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a config file that has some environment variable including a variable called MONGO_UUID and I pass this variable to a test step via a configFileProvider plugin and save it to .env file as in step below:

```
stage('Build ') {
    steps {
       configFileProvider([configFile(fileId: 'jenkins_config_filename', variable: "CONFIG_FILE")]) {                               
            sh '''              
                cp -f $CONFIG_FILE ./.env
                npm run test     // this step dynamically updates MONGO_UUID
                echo "$MONGO_UUID"  // trying to output newly updated value here

'''
jenkins_config_filename has following format:
MONGO_HOST=123.123.123.1
MONGO_DB=dbname
MONGO_US=user
MONGO_UUID=null
```

What I am trying to do is to output variable MONGO_UUID which was passed to the test step via config file and the value of MONGO_UUID get updated in the process. I can see that the MONGO_UUID got updated because I can see new record in mongodb but I am wondering how to echo that value in jenkins console.

Comment: what is the output you are getting currently  and what is expected output ?

Comment: I am not getting any output now and I am expecting UUID that was passed to mongodb by the test step just before it. If I cat the ./.env file then the MONGO_UUID is null there.

Answer (score 0):

add this line (with proper changes based on your MongoDB configuration) after `npm run test`:

```
MONGO_UUID=`mongo db.collection.find("whatever you query is")`
```

and then you can `echo` the variable to Jenkins output.
If you want to update the file, you can use `sed` like below :

```
sed -i "s/MONGO_UUID=.*/MONGO_UUID=${MONGO_UUID}/" .env
```